# spring rabbitmq wait confirm timeout

Tags: spring-rabbit

spring-rabbit version:1.7.4.RELEASE

this is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitmqConfiguration {

    public RabbitmqConfiguration(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,ConfirmCallback confirmCallback) throws Exception {
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(confirmCallback);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper));
    }

}

@Component
@Slf4j
public class OrderStatusChangeComponentImpl implements OrderStatusChangeComponent,ConfirmCallback{
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private OrderMessageLogComponent orderMessageLogComponent;
    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback#
     * confirm(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.CorrelationData, boolean,
     * java.lang.String)
     */
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
        long nowTime = System.nanoTime();

    String uuid = correlationData.getId();
    if (ack) {
        orderMessageLogComponent.deleteOrderMessageLogByUUID(uuid);
    } else {
        log.error(cause, nowTime);
    }
}
```

i test rabbitmq send msg by jmeter about 512 thread and 1000 loops;

i see log have so much error.
Channel shutdown: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: `#method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK, class-id=0, method-id=0)`

finally my application cannot connection rabbitmq.
btw my rabbitmq server is healty.

Comment: Please clarify "finally my application cannot connection rabbitmq" - what is the error?

Comment: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your `send()` within a `RabbitTemplate.invoke()` and invoke a `template.waitForConfirmsOrDie()` with a longer timeout.

If you are using `invoke()` and don't do that, the framework will only wait 5000ms for confirms.

If you are not using `invoke()`, it's not clear how you can get that close error.

Comment: There is no waitforconfirmsordie() function in rabbitmqtemplate in 1.7.4.RELEASE version of spring-rabbitmq. Anyway I found a method that I changed the content of confirm into asynchronous operation to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
    long nowTime = System.nanoTime();
    String uuid = correlationData.getId();
    if (ack) {
        orderMessageLogComponent.deleteOrderMessageLogByUUID(uuid);
    } else {
        log.error("消息发送失败，消息唯一标识为{}，具体原因为{}，当前时间为{}", uuid, cause, nowTime);
    }
}

@Override
@Async(MsgSendAsyncConfig.MSGSEND_SYNC_POOL)
public void deleteOrderMessageLogByUUID(String uuid) {
    orderMessageLogService.deleteOrderMessageLogByUUID(uuid);
}
```